# How does the passé composé change in passive voice?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, participe-passé, passif

I am having difficulty in getting the verb conjugation right in passive voice. I read somewhere that the verb takes the number and gender of the agent («subject» in English) . Is it true?

Consider the following sentences (which are confusing me, «?» indicates what I am not sure of):

- Le rapport a été fait (or faite?) par Gregoire.
- Julien atteinte (?) par Louise. (Is it the correct passive for “Louise attend Julien”?)
- Les matchs est regardés (?) par des milliers de spectateurs.
- La nouvelle est annoncée (?) par la presse.

And this one is really difficult

- Le chateau a été construit par l'architecte. (Is this sentence okay?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in the passive form, the past participle will take the number and gender of the subject. As for the auxiliary *être*, it'll follow the standard *passé composé* conjugation.

- *rapport* is masculine singular, so it should be

  > Le rapport **a été fait** par Grégoire.
- *Julien* is a boy's name. Also, the past participle for *attendre* (*to wait for*) is *attendu*, not *atteint* (which comes from *atteindre*, *to reach*)

  > Julian **est attendu** par Louise
- *matchs* is masculine plural (note that the tense of this sentence is not passé composé, but present)

  > Les matchs **sont regardés** par des milliers de spectateurs
- *nouvelle* is feminine singular (same as previous sentence, this is present tense)

  > La nouvelle **est annoncée** par la presse
- *chateau* is masculine singular

  > Le chateau **a été construit** par l'architecte

Comment: Salut Alexis. Pardon me for this but I have a basic question. in «Le rapport a été fait par Grégoire», isn't the subject Gregoire? It is not Gregoire who is doing the action on the report? Going by bullet points the form of verb depends on object, no?

Comment: Unless the terms are inverted between French and English grammars (none of which I'm a specialist in, I'm just a native French with a decent level of English), I think you are wrong. *rapport* is the subject (*sujet* in French) and *Grégoire* is the agent (*complément d'agent* in French). The fact that *Grégoire* is actually a person carrying out an action isn't relevant when determining the syntax role of the words.

Comment: I think this is a VERY useful point. Yes, English speakers should be careful in this respect.

Comment: Also, no être needed with attendre in the second sentence?

Comment: Or Julien est attendu par Louise?

Comment: Indeed. I just copied from your question.

Comment: I think you should fix your first sentence, the auxiliary doesn't “take the gender and the number” of the subject; it's more a standard verb ending based on the *person*. In particular gender is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez true, I didn't like the way I explained that neither. I just forgot to come back to it and improve...

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Done. If there's any room for improvement (and there surely is) feel free to edit the answer directly. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Passive voice is obtained with “être” as an auxiliary verb. *Être* is conjugated with the appropriate tense and followed with the past participle of the main verb.

One example in *present* tense:

> La souris est mangée par le chat.

To build passive with a compound tense, the same applies. The “être” auxiliary is conjugated using the “avoir” auxiliary (conjugated avoir + été) and the past participle of the main verb follows.

This example is in *passé composé* tense:

> La souris a été mangée par le chat.

Concerning agreements of past participles, only the one from the main verb receives distinctive inflections for feminine or plurals according to the same rules as for the active voice. Notice that the auxiliary of the main verb is always *être*. Hence, the agreement is made with the subject (here *la souris*), *not* with the agent (here *le chat*).